# Change speed countDownTimer dynamic

Tags: android, performance, countdowntimer

i got this code and i want to change the speed of the setText to my TextView. I want to go faster and the start but when the end is comming, slow that change of text.

```
            new CountDownTimer(10000, timeToChange) {

                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                    if (millisUntilFinished < 7000){
                        timeToChange = 500;
                        Log.d("changed", "time 7000 changed to : " + timeToChange);
                    } else if (millisUntilFinished < 5000){
                        timeToChange = 1000;
                        Log.d("changed", "time 5000 changed to : " + timeToChange);
                    } else if (millisUntilFinished < 3000){
                        timeToChange = 1500;
                        Log.d("changed", "time 3000 changed to : " + timeToChange);
                    }

                    if (controlador){
                        mTextField.setText("WORD 1");
                        controlador = false;
                    } else {
                        mTextField.setText("WORD2");
                        controlador = true;
                    }

                }

                public void onFinish() {
                    mTextField.setText("done!");
                    btnTime.setEnabled(true);
                }
            }.start();
```

This doesn't work which I think is obiouslly.

Is there any way to do it?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you should create a function that cancels the current `CountDownTimer` and create a new one with the new `timeToChange` you want :).

To do this, you can try to assign `CountDownTimer` to a variable to make things easier.

Answer (score 0):

Create your own CountDownTimer starting from the [Android one](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/os/CountDownTimer.java) and add a set method in order to change the variable mCountdownInterval.

Answer (score -1):

You can not Customize your duration after your CountDown Timer has been started
You have to use Thread to get your stuffs done.

With in thread you can use

```
Thread.sleep(your_duration);
```

so by this way you can handle speed.